# Как будет выглядеть схема хранения для многопользовательской работы с таблицами?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, postgresql, mongodb

По условию задачи нужно смоделировать работу с таблицами для пользователя.

Он может создавать таблицы. Каждый столбец таблицы имеет свой тип (`int`, `string`, `real`, `bool`, `foreign_key`).   Значение некоторых столбцов может ссылаться на значение столбцов других таблиц (`foreign_key`). Например, `users.id == post.user_id`. Каждая таблица наполняется своими записями.

Пользователь может делать выборки данных из таблиц, например: получить все записи из таблицы `users`, возраст которых `> 18` (`users.age > 18`). Подгружаются и связанные данные, если есть значение типа `foreign_key`.
Система многопользовательская, каждый пользователь может создавать свои таблицы, и у разных пользователей могут быть таблицы с одинаковыми именами.

Как будет выглядеть схема бд для таких действий? Какие бд лучше подходят под условие: реляционные или нереляционные? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: *Как будет выглядеть схема бд для таких действий?* Так же, как это выглядит на любом fiddle. Для пользователя создаётся персональная база данных. Внутри неё он бог и царь... а снаружи еле-еле поц.

Comment: @Akina В таком случае проблема с индексами будет. Придется ставить их для каждого юзера. Данных в таблицах может быть очень много.

Comment: Если юзер сам создаёт таблицы, сам наполняет их данными, сам пишет запросы - так пусть он и заботится об индексах. Или пусть сидит и ковыряет в носу, ожидая нужных ему результатов. На ТАКОЙ системе индексы - это НЕ забота хостера данных. А общие таблицы справочников, которые доступны любому юзеру, но лежат в служебных БД, ты проиндексируешь независимо.

Comment: @Akina  Работа с таблицами - это интерфейс, который видит пользователь. Чем представлены таблицы в бд, это уже проблема кодеров) Что такое индексы, для юзеров темный лес. Все это похоже чем-то на excel.

Comment: В таком разе - какие собсно индексы? обойдутся фуллсканом. Кстати, в рамках одной БД будет то же самое, никакой разницы. Ну или безусловно индексировать поля, которые юзер сам пометит как уникальные либо сильновариабельные (текстовые - на разумный префикс). Только всё один хрен гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: @Akina Ок, спасибо, отдельные базы, рассматривал) А вот если делать общую, единственный вариант это EAV со своими костылями?

Comment: Если делать общую, то, как ты сам отметил выше, придётся поверх собственно данных городить свою надстройку со слоем пользовательских метаданных (напр., *у разных пользователей могут быть таблицы с одинаковыми именами*) - не, вот оно тебе надо? Я уж не говорю о том, что сразу всплывает проблема разделения доступа и безопасности - да ты скрючишься городить ещё и собственную систему прав доступа поверх как данных, так и метаданных. А главное - я лично в упор не вижу ну никакого профита для поддержки, кроме копеечной экономии на отсутствии надобности в команде `use databasename`.

Comment: _Работа с таблицами - это интерфейс, который видит пользователь._ - Э-э-э... Серьёзно? А насколько квалифицирован пользователь? Обычно юзер видит GUI с текстбоксами, комбобоксами, чекбоксами... и знать не знает, что там за ними (может данные в плоских текстовых файлах хранятся).

Comment: Можно и в одной БД хранить данные всех пользователей. У каждого - своя схема. Разрешения только на работу с этой схемой, так что никто не повредит чужие данные.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov  Пользователь работает с таблицами, наподобие excel. И выборки делает указывается праметры  в GUI.  Вот насчет схемы, именно хранения "таблиц" мне пока непонятно.  Не уверен, что EAV оптимальное решение, хотя прототип сделал именно на EAV.   Не знаю насколько лучше и оптимальнее будет использование в задаче нереляционной бд.

Comment: Говоря "схема", я имел в виду следующее: [postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-createschema.html). В [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-database.html) как я понимаю, нет такого понятия.